# Display rows that have a zero count

Tags: sql, count, aggregate

I am trying to display rows even if they return a count of zero. However no luck. 
I tried using left join.

```
select
    a.Month,
    count(b.InsuranceFromJob) [Number of Participants without Insurance]
from
    hsAdmin.ReportPeriodLkup a
left join hsAdmin.ClientReport b on
    b.ReportPeriod = a.ReportPeriodId
where
    b.insurancefromjob = 2 and
    a.reportperiodid between (@lastReportId - 11) and @lastReportId
group by
    a.Month
```

Comment: try using `coalesce` or `zeroifnull` command in count . please mention database name .

Comment: You have constraints on table alias `b` in your `WHERE` clause, so you've effectively turned you `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: try moving predicate `b.insurancefromjob = 2` to `ON` clause

Comment: Thank you @GiorgosBetsos it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because clientreport is in the where, only rows that exists in clientreport will be in the resultset.

Move the check to the join and you will get the desired result:

```
select
    a.Month,
    count(b.InsuranceFromJob) [Number of Participants without Insurance]
from
    hsAdmin.ReportPeriodLkup a
left join hsAdmin.ClientReport b on
    b.ReportPeriod = a.ReportPeriodId
and b.insurancefromjob = 2
where
    a.reportperiodid between (@lastReportId - 11) and @lastReportId
group by
    a.Month
```